# ExtJS 3.4 ext.form.HtmlEditor clipboard sanitizing

Tags: extjs

If I paste HTML content from my clipboard into an ext.form.HtmlEditor editor, the html content gets sanitized. For example, html/head/body tags are gone, etc.

Does anyone know where this happens exactly in the ExtJS source code ?